# Accessing objects from list in other file

Tags: python, list, object

So i have two files User.py that contains User class and UserInformation.py that handles list of all Users created.
Why cant i access User data from my UserInformation.py list.
User.py:

```
class User(object):
    name = ""
    age = 0

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def toString(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name + ", Age: " + str(self.age))
```

And UserInformation.py

```
import User
listOfUsers = []


def addUser(User):
    listOfUsers.append(User)

def listUsers(User):
    x = 0
    while x < len(listOfUsers):
       listOfUsers[x].toString()
       x= x+1
```

What is wrong why cant i print User objects?

Comment: you may also consider not keeping User in listUsers(User) as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create instances of the `class` `User` for each of your users which you like to store in a `list`

Example:

```
from User import User
list_of_users = []


def add_user_to_list(User_instance):
    list_of_users.append(User_instance)

def list_users():
    x = 0
    while x < len(list_of_users):
        list_of_users[x].toString()
        x= x+1

def alternative_list_users():
    for user in list_of_users:
        user.toString()

def new_user(name, age):
    my_user_instance = User(name, age)
    add_user_to_list(my_user_instance)

def main():
    while True:
        name = input('user name ? ')
        if name == 'stop':
            break
        age = int(input('user age  ? '))
        new_user(name, age)
    list_users()
    #alternative_list_users()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that both the file and the class are called `User`. `import User` imports only the file (module). To import the *class*, you need to do:

```
from User import User
```

Though I would call the file `user.py` (lowercase) to avoid exactly this kind of confusion (I would also call the arguments to the functions something different).